# Parse a predicate builder - AND , OR , nested Brackets in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a string e.g.

```
categoryid = 2 
or ((categoryid = 3 and categoryid = 5) or (categoryid = 6 and categoryid = 7))
or ((categoryid =11 and (categoryid = 12 or categoryid = 13)) or (categoryid = 16 and categoryid = 17))
```

I am trying to convert this string into a tabular format so that it can be used for processing in the existing table. I cannot chnage the existing table structure, hence the challenge for me is to convert this string into a tabular structure.

While using loop based approach, I am getting stuck when I am encountering nested brackets as I am not able to understand which bracket is closing for which opening bracket.

```
Group   Condition   Operator    ParentGroup Relationship with NodeGroup (G1)
G1  categoryid = 2                          G1  
G2  categoryid = 3 and categoryid = 5   OR  G1  Or
G3  categoryid = 6 and categoryid = 7       G2  
G4  categoryid =11                      And G1  Or
G5  categoryid = 12 or categoryid = 13  Or  G4  
G6  categoryid = 16 and categoryid = 17     G4
```

Depending on whatver inputs I have , I need to convert the string into this tabular format.

Comment: It's probably irrelevant, but that expression can be simplified to `categoryid = 2` because everything else is always `false`. [Why do you need this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) anyway?

Comment: Wow! `(categoryid = 3 and categoryid = 5) = false`, `(categoryid = 6 and categoryid = 7) = false`, `(categoryid =11 and (categoryid = 12 or categoryid = 13) = false`, ... then `categoryid = 2 or false or false`, ... so just say `categoryid = 2`  ;).

Comment: in This case , it boils down to categoryid = 2 but if the expression is built with different inputs from the UI, the expression will be different.


There is a UI from where the user can create search expressions and theis expressions needs to be parsed to fetch the resulting data from the db.

Comment: I think you can use a *Rule Engine* or *Dynamic Filter* instead ;).

Comment: So, as I understand, the problem is not related with a SQL query but rather that you get a SQL condition as a *string value* and you need to parse it for storing the resulting tokens in a table. Also, you mention that you are using a loop so I think that you are doing it in the application and not with TSQL. Is this true? In that case, what language are you using for the application (C#, VB...)?

Comment: Alberto Martinez , The application is in C# which passes me the input in this format. I have the luxury of converting this input into tabular format in both SQL or C#. Currently I was trying to parse it in SQL.